# How to connect a Macbook Pro 16 to a high refresh rate monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I was recently looking to build a desktop setup powered by a 16 inch Macbook Pro (2019).

My biggest quarrel with Macbooks are their 60hz refresh rate screens and lack of graphical power due to using the AMD platform. Thus I wanted to incorporate all these worlds by building a system with a 1440p 165hz monitor and an Nvidia RTX 3080 E-GPU, with the heart of the setup being the Macbook Pro 16.

However, I havent been able to determine a few things:

1. If connected to an external monitor, will the Macbook be able to support the 165hz refresh rate
2. would I see effective results if I used a USB C to DisplayPort dongle to connect the the laptop to the monitor.
3. and finally if I could connect all the devices to the a Hub and connect only a singular USB C cable to my Macbook and have everything working perfectly fine.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I don't think Nvidia GPUs work with recent versions of macOS

Comment: I don't understand bullet point 1. If you are using an EGPU the Mac supports whatever the EGPU supports, or should. In 2, if you are using an EGPU you connect the monitor to the EGPU itself not the Mac. And 3 would depend on the EGPU. Some have hubs built-in. **You need to focus on one question here, and once that is answered ask another. AD works best that way.**